# Error on getting information in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I have a public function with query but I don't get all the informations correctly.

```
    public function getNextId($product_id,$product_category_id) {
    $query2zz = $this->db->query("
SELECT * 
  FROM oc_product_to_category a
  LEFT 
  JOIN oc_product b 
    ON a.product_id = b.product_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN oc_product_description c 
    ON c.product_id = a.product_id
  LEFT
  JOIN oc_url_alias d 
    ON d.query LIKE CONCAT('%', 'a.product_id', '%')
 WHERE a.product_id > '" . (int)$product_id . "' 
   AND a.category_id = '" . (int)$product_category_id . "'
   AND b.status = '1'
 ORDER 
    BY a.product_id ASC 
 LIMIT 1");
```

The idea is that I want to get next id for a next button. If you visit a product, you can click on next button, and you will go to next product on same category (clothes).
The problem is on oc_url_alias where I should get url for next id, as i mentioned here WHERE a.product_id > '" . (int)$product_id . "' but sometimes it get me wrong url (I mean get url for another product).
Thanks!

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Comment: Casting doesn't prevent sql injection

Comment: Should I replace " . (int)$product_id . " with mysql_real_escape_string(" . (int)$product_id . ") ?

Comment: Distinct * is oxymoronic

Comment: And `left join b... where b =...` is the same as `inner join b`

Comment: You shouldn't use PHP's deprecated mysql_ API for anything

Comment: Mysql_ methods are deprecated - Use Opencart's escaping method `$this->db->escape($product_id)`

Comment: Thanks! But still need some help here: LEFT
  JOIN oc_url_alias d 
    ON d.query LIKE CONCAT('%', 'a.product_id', '%'). The problem is that query is like that "product_id=1234" and a.product_id is just 1234. And it show me wrong results.